# Windows Batch File To Backup Files

Tags: batch-file, backup

I am new to writing windows batch scripts. I am trying to create a batch file that reads Filename and SourcePath from a CSV file & copies the file to a destination path. Destination path is partiall fixed and part of it comes from the source path. I am able to do it if i specify the destination path too in the CSV but i want to get that from the source path value.

A row in input file looks like this:

```
filename,C:\parent_dir\,path
```

This is what i have tried so far.

```
SET backup_dir=C:\backup_dir\
FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%A IN (list.csv) DO (
SET dest_dir="%backup_dir%%%C"
xcopy %%B%%C%%A %dest_dir% /e
PAUSE
)
PAUSE
```

This reads the file from parent dir properly but does not copy it to dest dir. Instead the files are being copied to the location where batch file is. I also have to add a timestamp to the file which is being backed up. I can get the timestamp value using this:

```
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~-4,4%_%DATE:~-7,2%_%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~-11,2%.%TIME:~-8,2%
```

but adding it to the filename before the extension is not working.  { I wish to change the filename from file.extn to file_timestamp.extn. } The extension of files can be different and therefore i cannot hardcode it.

Appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET BACKUP_DIR=C:\backup_dir\
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~-4,4%_%DATE:~-7,2%_%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~-11,2%.%TIME:~-8,2%
FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%A IN (list.csv) DO (
SET DEST_DIR="%BACKUP_DIR%%%C"
echo f | xcopy /f /y %%B%%C%%A !dest_dir!%%~nA_!TIMESTAMP!%%~xA 
)
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this below script ready, this will copy the files under source directory to destination directory (this information is stored in the input file input.txt)

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (input.txt) do CALL :DATACOPY "%%i" "%%j"
goto :eof

:DATACOPY "%%i" "%%j"
set source=%1
set dest=%2

for /f %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr /b [0-9]') do set TS=%%x

set yyyy=%TS:~0,4%
set mm=%TS:~4,2%
set dd=%TS:~6,2%
set hh=%TS:~8,2%
set min=%TS:~10,2%
set timestamp=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%_%hh%-%min%

robocopy  /TEE /S /E /TEE %source% %dest%_%timestamp%

:eof
```

Sample input file

```
source,destination
c:\source1\data,d:\dest1\data
c:\source1\data,d:\dest2\data
```

Cheers, G

Answer (score 0):

two issues:
 1. you set `backup_dir`, but use `dest_dir` in the loop.
2. batch scripts substitute variables early, before a block starts.
that means %dest_dir% in the xcopy will be fixed to the first value. to get around that, use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and then surround the variable with "!" instead of "%"

fiddling the timestamp between name and extension of %%A: `%%~nA!timestamp!%%~xA`

Putting it together (not tested):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET backup_dir=C:\backup_dir\
FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%A IN (list.csv) DO (
SET dest_dir="%backup_dir%%%C"
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~-4,4%_%DATE:~-7,2%_%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~-11,2%.%TIME:~-8,2%
xcopy %%B%%C%%~nA!timestamp!%%~xA !dest_dir! /e
PAUSE
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. I am using this line SET dest_dir="%backup_dir%%%C".  After making the change you suggested it is looking for a file with timestamp which does not exist. I am basically trying to rename the file before pasting it to backup_dir.

Comment: ok, then just replace the xcopy line with `copy %%B%%C%%A !dest_dir!\%%~nA!timestamp!%%~xA` to rename the file in the backup dir. or do you want to rename the original but retain the original filename in the backup?

Comment: Cannot replace with copy because i need the folders created automatically. I managed to tweak the logic a bit and have this solution which looks good for now. setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET BACKUP_DIR=C:\backup_dir\
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~-4,4%_%DATE:~-7,2%_%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~-11,2%.%TIME:~-8,2%
FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%A IN (list.csv) DO (
SET DEST_DIR="%BACKUP_DIR%%%C"
echo f | xcopy /f /y %%B%%C%%A !dest_dir!%%~nA_!TIMESTAMP!%%~xA 
)
PAUSE